# C# code to derive tangential points between two circles to create a trapezoid

Tags: c#, computational-geometry

These are the steps to determine coordinates of the 4 points (P1, P2, P3, P4) that make up a tangential trapezoid connecting to circles. Another way of looking at it is to think of the tangential segments of being the parts of a belt that would not be wrapped around the pulleys. The math should work regardless of the orientation of the two circles in coordinate space.

[image: diagram of shapes and points]

Code (usage @ bottom):

```
internal class TrapezoidBuilder
{
    private const double RadiansToDegrees = 180/Math.PI;
    private readonly double _bufferDistanceC0;
    private readonly double _bufferDistanceC1;

    private readonly Point _pointC0;
    private readonly Point _pointC1;
    public TrapezoidPoints TrapezoidPoints;

    public TrapezoidBuilder(Point pointC0, Point pointC1, double bufferDistanceC0, double bufferDistanceC1)
    {
        _pointC0 = pointC0;
        _pointC1 = pointC1;
        _bufferDistanceC0 = bufferDistanceC0;
        _bufferDistanceC1 = bufferDistanceC1;

        TrapezoidPoints = new TrapezoidPoints();

        CalculateTrapezoidPoints();
    }


    public void CalculateTrapezoidPoints()
    {
        // Get the angle of the line C0-C1 in degrees. This will be used in conjunction with angleA to determine the vector of these points
        double angleRelativeToPositiveXAxis = CalculateAngleRelativeToXAxis(_pointC0, _pointC1);

        // Get angleA
        double angleA = CalculateAngleA(_pointC0, _pointC1, _bufferDistanceC0, _bufferDistanceC1);

        ////  Calculate P1 and P2 coordinates first

        double positiveAngle = angleRelativeToPositiveXAxis + angleA;

        double cosPositiveAngle = Math.Cos(positiveAngle/RadiansToDegrees);

        double valueToAddToC0X = cosPositiveAngle*_bufferDistanceC0;

        // Set P1's X coordinate
        TrapezoidPoints.P1.X = _pointC0.X + valueToAddToC0X;

        double valueToAddToC1X = cosPositiveAngle*_bufferDistanceC1;

        // Set P2's X coordinate
        TrapezoidPoints.P2.X = _pointC1.X + valueToAddToC1X;

        double sinPositiveAngle = Math.Sin(positiveAngle/RadiansToDegrees);

        double valueToAddToC0Y = sinPositiveAngle*_bufferDistanceC0;

        // Set P1's Y coordinate
        TrapezoidPoints.P1.Y = _pointC0.Y + valueToAddToC0Y;

        double valueToAddToC1Y = sinPositiveAngle*_bufferDistanceC1;

        // Set P2's Y coordinate
        TrapezoidPoints.P2.Y = _pointC1.Y + valueToAddToC1Y;


        ////  Calculate P3 and P4 coordinates

        double negativeAngle = angleRelativeToPositiveXAxis - angleA;

        double cosNegativeAngle = Math.Cos(negativeAngle/RadiansToDegrees);

        valueToAddToC0X = cosNegativeAngle*_bufferDistanceC0;

        // Set P4's X coordinate
        TrapezoidPoints.P4.X = _pointC0.X + valueToAddToC0X;

        valueToAddToC1X = cosNegativeAngle*_bufferDistanceC1;

        // Set P3's X coordinate
        TrapezoidPoints.P3.X = _pointC1.X + valueToAddToC1X;

        double sinNegativeAngle = Math.Sin(negativeAngle/RadiansToDegrees);

        valueToAddToC0Y = sinNegativeAngle*_bufferDistanceC0;

        // Set P4's Y coordinate
        TrapezoidPoints.P4.Y = _pointC0.Y + valueToAddToC0Y;

        valueToAddToC1Y = sinNegativeAngle*_bufferDistanceC1;

        // Set P3's Y coordinate
        TrapezoidPoints.P3.Y = _pointC1.Y + valueToAddToC1Y;


        Debug.WriteLine("C0   " + _pointC0.X + "   " + _pointC0.Y);
        Debug.WriteLine("C1   " + _pointC1.X + "   " + _pointC1.Y);

        Debug.WriteLine("P1   " + TrapezoidPoints.P1.X + "   " + TrapezoidPoints.P1.Y);
        Debug.WriteLine("P2   " + TrapezoidPoints.P2.X + "   " + TrapezoidPoints.P2.Y);
        Debug.WriteLine("P3   " + TrapezoidPoints.P3.X + "   " + TrapezoidPoints.P3.Y);
        Debug.WriteLine("P4   " + TrapezoidPoints.P4.X + "   " + TrapezoidPoints.P4.Y);
    }

    private double CalculateAngleA(Point pointC0, Point pointC1, double radius0, double radius1)
    {
        double xDistance = pointC1.X - pointC0.X;
        double yDistance = pointC1.Y - pointC0.Y;

        double distance = Math.Sqrt((xDistance*xDistance) + (yDistance*yDistance));

        double radius2 = radius0 - radius1;

        double cosA = radius2/distance;

        double angleAInRadians = Math.Acos(cosA);

        double angleAInDegrees = angleAInRadians*RadiansToDegrees;

        return angleAInDegrees;
    }

    private double CalculateAngleRelativeToXAxis(Point point0, Point point1)
    {
        try
        {
            // In order to use ATAN2, point C1 has to be considered as the origin, i.e. 0, 0. 
            // So C1x is subtracted from C2x and C1y from C2y. Note that it’s important to subtract 
            // the 1st value from the 2nd to help determine which quadrant the angle is in.
            double x = point1.X - point0.X;
            double y = point1.Y - point0.Y;

            // Get the angle in radians
            double angleInRadians = Math.Atan2(x, y);

            // Convert to degrees
            double angleInDegrees = angleInRadians*RadiansToDegrees;

            // Subtract from 90 to get the angle relative to the positive X-axis
            double relativeAngleInDegrees = 90 - angleInDegrees;
            // Return result
            return relativeAngleInDegrees;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(err.Message);
        }

        // If no result, return zero
        return 0;
    }
}

internal class TrapezoidPoints
{
    public Point P1;
    public Point P2;
    public Point P3;
    public Point P4;
}


// Usage
Point C1 = new Point(5,7);
Point C2 = new Point(6.516, 7.875);
double buffer0 = 1;
double buffer1 = .375;

var trapezoidBuilder = new TrapezoidBuilder(C1, C2, buffer0, buffer1);
```

Comment: Great question but [pseudo code is off-topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#im-confused-what-questions-are-on-topic-for-this-site)

Comment: With all due respect (and I should have read the rules first), this policy isn't helpful. While I'm capable of posting actual code, it will become very specific (harder to wade through), will not provide a concrete example and would result in wasted effort if my general approach is wrong.

Comment: I'm just a member, but pseudo code has one huge disadvantage - you can't check if the code actually works or run it to ensure the changes you proposed would actually work.

Comment: That's a good point.

Comment: I've updated this post with code. So far, as much as I've been able to test it, it's doing what I want. I've been able to switch the circle sizes or make them the same and get the desired results.

Comment: This problem is perfect for F#. I would start out by writing out the formulas in LaTeX.

Comment: @Leonid Hmm. May have to take a look @ F#...always good to learn another language...just gotta find time.

Comment: One thing I caught in real world testing is that the distance between the circle centers has to be greater than the radius of the smaller circle. Otherwise, an error is thrown because the COS is outside the limits of -1 to 1. Also, the operation would be unnecessary anyway because one circle would be completely inside the other.

Comment: I have a suspicion that the math could be simpler...

Comment: You are using lots of unnecessary comments. Comment should explain why not what?

Comment: Uhm, what's the question being asked here?

Comment: As @miniBill asked, can you clarify what problem exactly you are having? Is the code not working properly? Are you seeking to shorten it? Refactor? Optimize for performance? Did you manage to solve it in the end?

Comment: @Stonetip, which software/script did you use to draw these pictures?

Comment: @Leonid I drew the picture in Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: Just revisiting this and have to say thanks for comments and answer from Ron. When I have time, I'll try to refactor. I'll also make sure to be clearer on what I'm asking next time. In this case, just hoping for a general review.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's not clear to me what are `buffer0` and `buffer1`? If these represent the radius values (like C1-P1 line for `buffer1`), then perhaps `radius0` (and `radius1`) would be a better name here.
2. I'd create and use a data class for each point-radius pair. Say, `InputPoint` class with `Point` and `Radius` or something similar.
3. I'd separate constructor and results. The results are calculations that should not be part of the constructor. Take, for example, the class named [`UriBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) in .NET: you can construct it, change the inputs, and only when you call the property named `Uri` - you get the calculated uri. The same should apply here, too. Constructing a class gives us an instance with a valid state. Calculations - in their own methods or property-getters (that are practically methods, by the way). So `TrapezoidPoints` should be the returned type of a `GetTrapezoid` method (or maybe `TryGetTrapezoid` if this pattern apply here), and not part of the class' state.